# If statement with swig res.locals.user insert html attribute

Tags: swig-template

I am using the swig template engine with express and am trying to pass req.user through to the template inside a callback. I need to check and see what plan they are using so that the checked input will show the correct one for the radio button.

Partial route:

```
(req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  console.log(res.locals.user.stripe.plan); // this shows the value I need
  next();
    }
```

If statement I am trying to use:

```
<input type="radio"  {% if user.stripe.plan == "free" %}checked{% endif %} name="plan" value="free" data-toggle="radio">
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do to debug this is output the value directly into the HTML, so `{{ user.stripe.plan }}`. That will confirm what value actually makes it to the template. Note that any locals you pass to `res.render` will overwrite those in `res.locals` so it might be worth experimenting with a crazy name like `res.locals.somethingCrazy` and `somethingCrazy.stripe.plan`, just to check nothing else is changing the value along the way.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method of doing this is `{{ if plans[user.stripe.plan].name|lower === 'silver'}}<strong>silver</strong>{% endif %}`

Doing `plans[user.stripe.plan].name` gives you the plan name which you then use `|lower` to make it easier to compare to `silver`. Just put that inside an if statement and you are good to go.